# In Qt QObject::connect problems with move()

Tags: qt

Ok so when I run this (wrote it up just to display the problem) :

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QtGUI>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QWidget *window = new QWidget;

    QPushButton *MainInter = new QPushButton("Push me!",window);

    QObject::connect(MainInter,SIGNAL(released()),MainInter,SLOT(move(100,100)));

    window->resize(900,500);
    window->show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Why doesn't the button move when clicked? :)

Comment: You might be better off asking [here](http://www.qtcentre.org/forum.php).

Comment: You misunderstood about signals and slots. In Qt, connecting one signal with a slot, means that call slot function with **the same parameters of signal function**, if the slot function accept enough parameters. Thus, set parameters in `connect()` won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`move` is not a slot, but an accessor to change the `pos` property, it can't be connected directly to a signal. But you can connect the signal to the `start()` slot of `QPropertyAnimation` which will change that property:

```
QPushButton *MainInter = new QPushButton("Push me!",window);

QPropertyAnimation *animation = new QPropertyAnimation(MainInter, "pos");
// To make the move instantaneous
animation->setDuration(0);
animation->setEndValue(QPoint(100,100));

QObject::connect(MainInter, SIGNAL(released()), animation, SLOT(start()));
...
```

or make that property value part of a state of a `QStateMachine` and use the signal to transition to that state:

```
QPushButton *MainInter = new QPushButton("Push me!",window);

QStateMachine *machine = new QStateMachine();
QState *s1 = new QState(machine);
QState *s2 = new QState(machine);
// the transition replaces the connect statement
s1->addTransition(MainInter, SIGNAL(released()), s2);
s2->assignProperty(MainInter, "pos", QPoint(100,100));
machine->setInitialState(s1);
machine->start();    
...
```

Comment: Thank you so much alexisdm the QProperty animation method worked great! :)

Answer (score 1):

The signal and slot must have the same [signature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_signature). Actually slot can have a shorter signature than the signal:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html

In your case, it's the opposite: slot has a longer signature. You may try [`QSignalMapper`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsignalmapper.html) to create a "broker" to relay the signal with additional parameters.